# Multi-column list with <li>

Tags: css

I'm using ul/li to create a multi column gallery view of a wordpress category. But all rows except the first gets a left margin..

I can't see what i'm doing wrong!

http://spirit.no/category/musikkanmeldelser/

Do I have solve this with a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no margin on the first list item because of a style that applies to the `:first-child` of that container. You can remove the margin after every third list item with

```
.last-posts li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

This will display your list items in three columns, as I assume you intend.

Comment: Good suggestion, [here's support information](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth) for `nth-child`, good except with IE, naturally!

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by this CSS:

```
.last-posts li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

http://spirit.no/wp-content/themes/spirit/style.css line 235

Which is overriding the `margin-left` given to `.last-posts li` elements with this CSS:

```
.last-posts li.the-post {
  width: 290px;
  min-height: 270px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

You could either get rid of the `:first-child` CSS or add a class to every post first on the line that receives `margin-left: 0px;`. That is up to you, there are many approaches

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a left margin or padding on your image. Change this to a right pad or margin and make sure you factor in the padding/margin width into the width of the `li` element:

```
.last-posts li.the-post {
    width: 290px;           <== subtract margin/padding width here
    min-height: 270px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you have a left margin set up:

```
.last-posts li.the-post {
width: 290px;
min-height: 270px;
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
position: relative;
}
```

The spacing offsets every row after the first.